# Array walker C language

Tags: c, arrays

Here is the task:

> Project U6: Array Walker
>   Write a program that computes a ”walk” (of a cute robot) across a 10x10 array. The
>   array contains characters (all initially ’.’). The user can enter four different directions
>   north, east, south, west, by entering the characters n,e,s,w to control the walk. If the user
>   enters x the program exits. After each direction-command the array is printed with the
>   walk being display by capital letter starting with A to Z. We use A for the starting point,
>   with 25 remaining letters to denote the steps. After having used letter Z to denote a step,
>   we wrap around and start again with A. To make the walk more interesting, the user is
>   not allowed to revisit a location. In this case the program does not print the array, but
>   prints ”You cannot go there!” - Yes, you can trap yourself.
>   Starting in the upper left corner (position 0,0):

Thats what i have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define M 26
#define N 10
#define K 10

int main()
{
    char A[N][K],direction;
    char let[26] =     {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    int i=0,j=0,m=0;
    for(i=0; i<N; ++i)
        for(j=0; j<K; ++j)
            A[i][j]='.';
    for(i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {   A[0][0]=let[0];
        for(j=0; j<K; ++j)
            printf("%c",A[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
    }
    getch();

    scanf("%c",&direction);
        for(m=1;m<26;m++){
            if (direction=='E')

            for(i=0; i<N; ++i){       //i don't think that the way that im thinking here is rigth
                 A[0][0]=let[0];
                 m=i+1;
                 A[m][j++]=let[m];
            for(j=0; j<K; ++j)
                printf("%c",A[i][j]);
                printf("\n");}
                return direction;
            }

    return 0;
}
```

I know that i'm not even close to solution, but i rly want to know how to make it.
I can't understand how to change '.' on a following letter, and remember all that positions.

Comment: `m=i+1` looks extremely wrong in its current location. You should probably just use `i+1` instead of `m`.

Comment: In addition, what's the point in `return direction` (to whom are you returning it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define M 26
#define N 10
#define K 10

int main()
{
    char A[N][K],direction;
    char let[M] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    char start='A';
    int x=0,y=0;
    int i=0,j=0,m,k;

    for(i=0; i<N; ++i){
        for(j=0; j<K; ++j)
            A[i][j]='.';}

        for(i=0; i<N; ++i){
                A[0][0]=let[0];
            for(j=0; j<K; ++j)
                printf("%c",A[i][j]);
                printf("\n");
                    }

    k=0;
    A[x][y]=let[k];

if (direction == 's' && x==9 || direction=='e' && y==9 || direction=='w' && y==0 || direction=='n' && x==0){
            printf("You cannot go there!\n");}

do{
        if (direction =='x'){break;}

        if (direction!='\n'){
            printf("Enter direction command: ");}
            direction=getchar();

        if (direction=='s' && A[x+1][y]!='.'){
              printf("You cannot go there!\n");

        }else if(direction=='s') {
                x++;
                k++;
                A[x][y]=let[k];
                    for(i=0; i<N; ++i){
                        for(j=0; j<K; ++j)
                            printf("%c",A[i][j]);
                            printf("\n");}
        }

        if (direction=='e' && A[x][y+1]!='.'){
              printf("You cannot go there!\n");

        }else if (direction=='e'){
            y++;
            k++;
            A[x][y]=let[k];
                 for(i=0; i<N; ++i){
                        for(j=0; j<K; ++j)
                            printf("%c",A[i][j]);
                            printf("\n");}
        }

        if (direction=='w' && A[x][y-1]!='.'){
              printf("You cannot go there!\n");

        }else if (direction=='w'){
            y--;
            k++;
            A[x][y]=let[k];
                    for(i=0; i<N; ++i){
                        for(j=0; j<K; ++j)
                            printf("%c",A[i][j]);
                            printf("\n");}

        }

        if (direction=='n' && A[x-1][y]!='.'){
              printf("You cannot go there!\n");

        }else if (direction=='n'){
            x--;
            k++;
            A[x][y]=let[k];
                    for(i=0; i<N; ++i){
                        for(j=0; j<K; ++j)
                            printf("%c",A[i][j]);
                            printf("\n");}
            }
        } while (k!=26);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you the entire code ,but just give you some tips and hints.

First of all,call

```
A[0][0]=let[0];
```

**once** at the start of `main`.Then,use create a function named `dispgrid` or something like that with

```
    for(i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {   
        for(j=0; j<K; ++j)
            printf("%c",A[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
    }
```

In its body. Remember that

```
 char A[N][K];
```

Should be declared as global because other functions also will need it. You will be needing a pointer to iterate through the letter array. So declare

```
char *ptr=let;
```

You will also need two variables which denotes the current x and y coordinates of the robot. So declare

```
int x=0,y=0; //starting at position (0,0)
```

I imagine the grid with the top-left corner having coodinates (0,0) and bottom-right corner having coordinates (-9,-9). Then,create a loop which terminates when `direction` is `x`. Scan user input and store it in `direction`. Then,check if it is `n` . If it is,check if `y` is 0 and if `a[x][y-1]` is not `.` . If it is,then print "You cannot go there" and continue the loop. Else,do `y--` and then if `ptr` is `Z`,`ptr=let` and `[x][y-1]=ptr;`else,`ptr++;` and then, `a[x][y-1]=ptr;`. Continue the loop after that.

Now,Implement the above idea,changing the respective variables when neccesary when `direction` is `e`,`w` and `s`.

Comment: Thanks alot for help! I would not do this without ur hints, sir.

Comment: Good Job accomplishing your task ! :)